# How to get dynamic path from Next.js 13 Middleware?

Tags: next.js, middleware, next.js13

I am currently trying to retrieve this slug value when the /@slug path is in the middleware.

That slug value could be @dfdnsjvnds
@abcscs That might be it.

How should path pattern matching be done in this situation?

```js
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const { pathname, searchParams } = request.nextUrl;

  console.log("pathname: ", pathname);

  if (pathname === "/@") {
    console.log("pathWorking! ") // not working
  }


}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/", "/@:path*"],
};
```

Comment: Since you always have the same prefix I think `pathname.startWith("/@")` should work? Are you sure your match is correct, do you see "pathname" in the logs?